# how to speed up a cross join with having?

Tags: mysql

I have to combine the data of two tables, movcampagna and catalogo with an a cross join. I have to filter the results based on the sum of the NumeroPunti of all the movcampagna lines. That's why I used HAVING. Unfortunately, about 20 seconds to execute very slowly. Is there a faster way to run this query?

NOTE: I have to get totals point  (all movacampagna lines with the same idCliente) before the where clause which is why I used CROSS JOIN

```
SELECT movcampagna.idCliente AS idCliente,
  movcampagna.idLoyaltyCard AS idLoyaltyCard,
  movcampagna.idCampagna AS idCampagna,
  movcampagna.Nome AS Nome,
  movcampagna.Cognome AS Cognome,
  Sum(movcampagna.NPunti) AS NPunti,
  catalogo.idCatalogo AS idCatalogo,
  catalogo.Nome AS NomePremio,
  catalogo.Punti AS Punti,
  catalogo.PrezzoAdd AS `Prezzo+`,
  catalogo.PuntiAdd AS `Punti+`,
  catalogo.Attivo AS Attivo
FROM (catalogo
  CROSS JOIN movcampagna)
WHERE catalogo.Attivo = '1'
GROUP BY movcampagna.idCliente,
  catalogo.idCatalogo
HAVING NPunti >= catalogo.Punti AND catalogo.Punti > 0
  OR
  NPunti >= catalogo.PuntiAdd AND catalogo.PuntiAdd > 0

Table MovCampagna
+---------------+-----------+---------+---------+--------+
| idMovCampagna | idCliente | Nome    | Cognome | NPunti |
+---------------+-----------+---------+---------+--------+
| 1             | 1         | Janeta  | Marin   | 20     |
+---------------+-----------+---------+---------+--------+
| 2             | 1         | Janeta  | Marin   | 10     |
+---------------+-----------+---------+---------+--------+
| 3             | 2         | Adelina | Rossi   | 10     |
+---------------+-----------+---------+---------+--------+
| 4             | 2         | Adelina | Rossi   | 10     |
+---------------+-----------+---------+---------+--------+
| 5             | 3         | Anna    | Brevi   | 30     |
+---------------+-----------+---------+---------+--------+
| 6             | 2         | Adelina | Rossi   | 40     |
+---------------+-----------+---------+---------+--------+
| 7             | 1         | Janeta  | Marin   | 40     |
+---------------+-----------+---------+---------+--------+
| 8             | 3         | Anna    | Brevi   | 10    |
+---------------+-----------+---------+---------+--------+

Table Catalogo

+------------+------------+-------+----------+-----------+
| idCatalogo | NomePremio | Punti | PuntiAdd | PrezzoAdd |
+------------+------------+-------+----------+-----------+
| 1          | AAAA       | 60    | 40       | 10        |
+------------+------------+-------+----------+-----------+
| 2          | BBBB       | 70    | 50       | 10        |
+------------+------------+-------+----------+-----------+
| 3          | CCCC       | 80    | 60       | 10        |
+------------+------------+-------+----------+-----------+
| 4          | DDDD       | 50    | 20       | 20        |
+------------+------------+-------+----------+-----------+
```

eg:result

```
+-----------+---------+---------+--------+------------+------------+-------+----------+-----------+------------+
| idCLiente | Nome    | Cognome | NPunti | idCatalogo | NomePremio | Punti | PuntiAdd | PrezzoAdd | idCampagna |
+-----------+---------+---------+--------+------------+------------+-------+----------+-----------+------------+
| 1         | Janeta  | Marin   | 70     | 1          | AAAA       | 60    | 40       | 10        | 1          |
+-----------+---------+---------+--------+------------+------------+-------+----------+-----------+------------+
| 1         | Janeta  | Marin   | 70     | 2          | BBBB       | 70    | 50       | 10        | 1          |
+-----------+---------+---------+--------+------------+------------+-------+----------+-----------+------------+
| 1         | Janeta  | Marin   | 70     | 3          | CCCC       | 80    | 60       | 10        | 1          |
+-----------+---------+---------+--------+------------+------------+-------+----------+-----------+------------+
| 1         | Janeta  | Marin   | 70     | 4          | DDDD       | 50    | 20       | 20        | 1          |
+-----------+---------+---------+--------+------------+------------+-------+----------+-----------+------------+
| 2         | Adelina | Rossi   | 60     | 1          | AAAA       | 60    | 40       | 10        | 1          |
+-----------+---------+---------+--------+------------+------------+-------+----------+-----------+------------+
| 2         | Adelina | Rossi   | 60     | 3          | CCCC       | 80    | 60       | 10        | 1          |
+-----------+---------+---------+--------+------------+------------+-------+----------+-----------+------------+
| 2         | Adelina | Rossi   | 60     | 4          | DDDD       | 50    | 20       | 20        | 1          |
+-----------+---------+---------+--------+------------+------------+-------+----------+-----------+------------+
| 3         | Anna    | Brevi   | 40     | 3          | AAAA       | 60    | 40       | 10        | 1          |
+-----------+---------+---------+--------+------------+------------+-------+----------+-----------+------------+
| 3         | Anna    | Brevi   | 40     | 2          | DDDD       | 50    | 20       | 20        | 1          |
+-----------+---------+---------+--------+------------+------------+-------+----------+-----------+------------+
|           |         |         |        |            |            |       |          |           |            |
+-----------+---------+---------+--------+------------+------------+-------+----------+-----------+------------+
|           |         |         |        |            |            |       |          |           |            |
+-----------+---------+---------+--------+------------+------------+-------+----------+-----------+------------+
|           |         |         |        |            |            |       |          |           |            |
+-----------+---------+---------+--------+------------+------------+-------+----------+-----------+------------+
|           |         |         |        |            |            |       |          |           |            |
+-----------+---------+---------+--------+------------+------------+-------+----------+-----------+------------+
```

Comment: Show you indexes

Comment: It's not that obvious if your only language is english and it's not obvious why a cross join is used.

Comment: the two tables do not have common indices. I use a cross because I have to repeat the same idCliente where the sum of the NumeroPunti follows the HAVING logic in the catalogo table. Sorry if I don't write well in English.

Answer (score 0):

@GT73 it looks like you're doing something wrong. `Sum(movcampagna.NumeroPunti)` will always be equal to `movcampagna.NumeroPunti * count of rows in catalogo`. Are you sure you need exactly that?

Maybe you wanted this actually (see below)?

```sql
SELECT movcampagna.idCliente AS idCliente,
  movcampagna.idLoyaltyCard AS idLoyaltyCard,
  movcampagna.Nome AS Nome,
  movcampagna.Cognome AS Cognome,
  movcampagna.NC AS NC,
  movcampagna.BarCode AS BarCode,
  movcampagna.Telefono AS Telefono,
  movcampagna.NumeroPunti AS NumeroPunti,
  catalogo.Punti AS Punti,
  catalogo.PrezzoAdd AS `Prezzo+`,
  catalogo.PuntiAdd AS `Punti+`,
  catalogo.Categoria AS Categoria,
  catalogo.idCatalogo AS idCatalogo,
  catalogo.Nome AS NomePremio,
  catalogo.PathImmagine AS PathImmagine,
  movcampagna.idCampagna AS idCampagna,
  catalogo.Attivo AS Attivo
FROM catalogo
JOIN movcampagna ON movcampagna.NumeroPunti >= catalogo.Punti AND catalogo.Punti > 0
  OR movcampagna.NumeroPunti >= catalogo.PuntiAdd AND catalogo.PuntiAdd > 0
WHERE catalogo.Attivo = '1'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need the "total" of NumeroPunti of all the lines for the same customer to compare it with the Punti and PuntiAdd fields. If I run your query I have a NumeroPunti of 133 against the actual 990, for example for the customer ID 1.

Comment: the problem and with this join I don't have the total points. I have to have the total points from the movcampagna table and then do the join